# How to connect Redis cluster from application in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: redis, kubernetes, cluster-computing, minikube, kubernetes-helm

This is my application code:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host=os.getenv("REDIS", "redis"), db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Here want to connect a Redis host in the Kubernetes cluster. So put a environment variable `REDIS` to set value in Kubernetes' manifest file.

This is the Kubernetes deployment manifest file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
            - name: REDIS
              value: {{ template "fullname" . }}-master-svc
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
    {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

In order to connect Redis host in the same cluster, set environment value as:

```
      env:
        - name: REDIS
          value: {{ template "fullname" . }}-master-svc
```

About Redis cluster, installed by official [redis-ha](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/redis-ha) chart. Its master service manifest file is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}-master-svc
  annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.servers.annotations | indent 4 }}
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: "redis-ha"
    redis-node: "true"
    redis-role: "master"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
  type: "{{ .Values.servers.serviceType }}"
```

But it seems that the application pod didn't connect to the Redis master service name successfully. When I got accessed URL:

```
export NODE_PORT=$(kubectl get --namespace default -o jsonpath="{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}" services wishful-rabbit-mychart)
export NODE_IP=$(kubectl get nodes --namespace default -o jsonpath="{.items[0].status.addresses[0].address}")
echo http://$NODE_IP:$NODE_PORT
```

from browser, got this result:

```
Hello World!

Hostname: wishful-rabbit-mychart-85dc7658c6-9blg5
Visits: cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled
```

More information about `pods` and `services`:

```
kubectl get po
NAME                                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
wishful-rabbit-mychart-bdfdf6558-8fjmb             1/1       Running   0          8m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-bdfdf6558-9khfs             1/1       Running   0          7m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-bdfdf6558-hgqxv             1/1       Running   0          8m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-sentinel-8667dd57d4-9njwq   1/1       Running   0          37m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-sentinel-8667dd57d4-jsq6d   1/1       Running   0          37m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-sentinel-8667dd57d4-ndqss   1/1       Running   0          37m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd-2fn4s     1/1       Running   0          37m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd-bwgrq     1/1       Running   0          37m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd-spkkm     1/1       Running   0          37m

kubectl get svc
NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes                          ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        3h
wishful-rabbit-mychart              NodePort    10.101.103.224   <none>        80:30033/TCP   37m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc   ClusterIP   10.108.128.167   <none>        6379/TCP       37m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-sentinel     ClusterIP   10.107.63.208    <none>        26379/TCP      37m
wishful-rabbit-mychart-slave-svc    ClusterIP   10.99.211.111    <none>        6379/TCP       37m
```

What's the right usage?

---

## Redis Server Pod Env

```
kubectl exec -it wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd-2fn4s -- sh
/ # printenv
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.108.128.167
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SERVICE_HOST=10.101.103.224
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
HOSTNAME=wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd-2fn4s
SHLVL=1
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
HOME=/root
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_SERVICE_HOST=10.107.63.208
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT=tcp://10.101.103.224:80
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.99.211.111:6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SERVICE_PORT=80
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_SERVICE_PORT=26379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT=tcp://10.107.63.208:26379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.108.128.167:6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR=10.101.103.224
REDIS_CHART_PREFIX=wishful-rabbit-mychart-
TERM=xterm
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT_80_TCP_PORT=80
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT_80_TCP_PROTO=tcp
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT_26379_TCP_ADDR=10.107.63.208
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT_80_TCP=tcp://10.101.103.224:80
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_SERVICE_HOST=10.99.211.111
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT_26379_TCP_PORT=26379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT_26379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_SERVICE_HOST=10.108.128.167
PWD=/
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_SERVICE_PORT=6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT=tcp://10.99.211.111:6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SERVICE_PORT_HTTP=80
REDIS_SENTINEL_SERVICE_HOST=redis-sentinel
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.99.211.111
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT_26379_TCP=tcp://10.107.63.208:26379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT=tcp://10.108.128.167:6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_SERVICE_PORT=6379
```

---

## Application Pod Env

```
kubectl exec -it wishful-rabbit-mychart-85dc7658c6-8wlq6 -- sh
# printenv
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.108.128.167
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SERVICE_HOST=10.101.103.224
HOSTNAME=wishful-rabbit-mychart-85dc7658c6-8wlq6
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=9.0.1
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_SERVICE_HOST=10.107.63.208
HOME=/root
GPG_KEY=C01E1CAD5EA2C4F0B8E3571504C367C218ADD4FF
REDIS=wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SERVICE_PORT=80
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT=tcp://10.101.103.224:80
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.99.211.111:6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.108.128.167:6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_SERVICE_PORT=26379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT=tcp://10.107.63.208:26379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR=10.101.103.224
NAME=World
TERM=xterm
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT_80_TCP_PORT=80
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT_80_TCP_PROTO=tcp
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
LANG=C.UTF-8
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT_26379_TCP_ADDR=10.107.63.208
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_SERVICE_HOST=10.99.211.111
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_PORT_80_TCP=tcp://10.101.103.224:80
PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.14
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT_26379_TCP_PORT=26379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT_26379_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_SERVICE_HOST=10.108.128.167
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
PWD=/app
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT=tcp://10.99.211.111:6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SERVICE_PORT_HTTP=80
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_SERVICE_PORT=6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SLAVE_SVC_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.99.211.111
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_SENTINEL_PORT_26379_TCP=tcp://10.107.63.208:26379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_SERVICE_PORT=6379
WISHFUL_RABBIT_MYCHART_MASTER_SVC_PORT=tcp://10.108.128.167:6379
```

### All Endpoints

```
kubectl get ep
NAME                                ENDPOINTS                                              AGE
kubernetes                          10.0.2.15:8443                                         4h
wishful-rabbit-mychart              172.17.0.5:80,172.17.0.6:80,172.17.0.7:80              1h
wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc   <none>                                                 1h
wishful-rabbit-mychart-sentinel     172.17.0.11:26379,172.17.0.12:26379,172.17.0.8:26379   1h
wishful-rabbit-mychart-slave-svc    <none>
```

---

## Describe Redis Master Service

```
kubectl describe svc wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc
Name:              wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=redis-ha,redis-node=true,redis-role=master,release=wishful-rabbit
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.108.128.167
Port:              <unset>  6379/TCP
TargetPort:        6379/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

---

## Describe Redis Server Pod

```
kubectl describe po wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd-2fn4s
Name:           wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd-2fn4s
Namespace:      default
Node:           minikube/192.168.99.100
Start Time:     Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:28:42 +0900
Labels:         app=mychart
                chart=mychart-0.1.0
                heritage=Tiller
                name=redis-server
                pod-template-hash=3029038988
                podIP=172.17.0.10
                redis-node=true
                redis-role=master
                release=wishful-rabbit
                runID=cbf8e0
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd","uid":"4fcb0dfc-07e2-1...
Status:         Running
IP:             172.17.0.10
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd
Containers:
  redis:
    Container ID:   docker://2734d60bd44a1446ec6556369359ed15b866a4589abe1e6d394f9252114c6d4d
    Image:          quay.io/smile/redis:4.0.6r2
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://quay.io/smile/redis@sha256:8948a952920d4495859c984546838d4c9b4c71e0036eef86570922d91cacb3df
    Port:           6379/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 02 Feb 2018 15:28:44 +0900
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      REDIS_SENTINEL_SERVICE_HOST:  redis-sentinel
      REDIS_CHART_PREFIX:           wishful-rabbit-mychart-
    Mounts:
      /redis-master-data from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-wfv2q (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          True
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
  default-token-wfv2q:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-wfv2q
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     <none>
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: You have shared manifest file templates rather than the actual manifest files. These are not very useful in order to help you with your problem. I suggest entering your application pod with `kubectl exec` and checking the actual value of the REDIS env var, and try connecting from in there to understand a little more about the issue.

Comment: @whites11 I think the key point of the problem is that how to connect that `redis-ha` cluster from environment variable. I have checked the `Redis Master` pod environment variables. Got hostname of `HOSTNAME=wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd-2fn4s`. Can't use it because the `746f47dfdd-2fn4s` is dynamic change. The `REDIS_SENTINEL_SERVICE_HOST=redis-sentinel` is used for connect sentinel. Still not clear which ENV to connect.

Comment: You need to check your application pods' env vars, not redis ones.

Comment: And also add `$ kubectl get endpoints`

Comment: @whites11 Added application pod env to the above of the question. It has `REDIS=wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc`, but can't reach `wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc` service.

Comment: @aerokite Added result of all endpoints in the Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Ok so you got your problem. As you can see your application pod as a correct ENV var: `REDIS=wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc` but your redis service has no endpoints as you can tell from this line: `wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc   <none>`. This means your redis instance is not healthy. Probably the pods are not running for some reason or the service selector is wrong. This is weird though because you used a template to run redis.

Comment: What does `kubectl describe svc wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc` say?

Comment: @whites11 All of the Redis pods and services are Running all the time. The `redis-ha` cluster looks good. I just use the default settings. And, I added result of describe `Redis Master Service`.

Comment: now please also post: `kubectl describe po wishful-rabbit-mychart-server-746f47dfdd-2fn4s`

Comment: @whites11 Posted Redis server pod's description.

Comment: `wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc` do not have any endpoint

Comment: Check your master Pod labels and master Service selector. They do not match

Comment: @aerokite Yes, the default `redis-ha` chart doesn't set endpoint for master. So can't use it?

Comment: No. It service do not have endpoint, you can't your service. it will not work

Comment: @JingqiangZhang, check my answer.

Comment: I think I got the problem first. I answered it in comment: https://m1r.site/2FCSKmP. See last 5 comments here. I think you should accept my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a discrepancy between your `wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc` service's `Selector` and your master redis pods' `labels`.

Your service is searching for pods with the following labels:

```
app=redis-ha
redis-node=true
redis-role=master
release=wishful-rabbit
```

While your pods have the following labels:

```
app=mychart
chart=mychart-0.1.0
heritage=Tiller
name=redis-server
pod-template-hash=3029038988
podIP=172.17.0.10
redis-node=true
redis-role=master
release=wishful-rabbit
runID=cbf8e0
```

As you can see the `app` label is different (`redis-ha` in your service, `mychart` in your pods).

This causes the service to be unbounded (it doesn't know where to forward the incoming traffic).

While I don't know the actual cause of this configuration error, I can suggest a solution to make it work.

You have to edit your redis service and change its selector attribute in order to match the pod's labels. Just run:

```
kubectl edit svc wishful-rabbit-mychart-master-svc
```

and change `app: "redis-ha"` with `app: "mychart"`.

Your application should suddenly be able to reach your redis instance.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for your right answer very much! I will show you why this issue happened. I am using `Helm` to include my application and `redis-ha` context in the same chart. In my application, I named its `Selector` with `mychart`. Then copied `redis-ha` files to the same direcotry with its default `Selector` `redis-ha`, so they are not matching! 
https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/redis-ha/templates/redis-master-service.yaml#L13

Answer (score 1):

> A Kubernetes Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods. The set of Pods targeted by a Service is (usually) determined by a Label Selector

So, Pods can be targeted by Service with the help of selector.

> The Service’s selector will be evaluated continuously and the results will be POSTed to an Endpoints object.

If, no Pod found with your provided selector, no valid Endpoint will be created.

In this case, if you use this Service to access Pod, this will not work, because DNS will not get any IP address from Endpoint

To learn more, [read how Service works](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Comment: Check this. This will help you to understand the scenario properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have got the key reason now! You and @whites11 gave me a very right solution and explanation!